# What do two spots mean in the GLM model validation graphs?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lognormal-distribution, zero-inflation

I performed a hurdle (delta) model to estimate the relative indices of abundance of a fish species. Thus, the catch estimates involved fitting separately two ‘sub-models’ to the data. The first sub-model modelled the probability that a positive observation occurs assuming a binomial error distribution, and the positive observations were analyzed using a second sub-model assuming a lognormal error distribution.

After selecting the set of explanatory factors, model checking and fit diagnostics were used to validate the model:

(1) the Pearson residuals vs. fitted values;
(2) the standardized deviance residuals vs. the estimated linear predictor, and
(3) the scale-adjusted dependent variable vs. the estimated linear predictor

But, I found two spots in my plots for positive catches (lognormal error distribution). Can anyone explain the cause of this?

```
m2 <- glm(log(CPUE) ~ (year + quarter +  vessel + port +  target),
          family = gaussian (link="identity"))
```

PS: All explanatory factors are categoricals.

[image: Model checking]

Comment: The x axis in your graphs are the linear predictions. Do you happen to have one covariate that has strong effects on the outcome but only has two potential categories (e.g. two years, or two vessels, etc.)

Comment: There is no bias offhand - it just suggests your data are clustered into only two groups for the explanatory variables.

Comment: Ok, tks so much Andy!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? It doesn't make sense that the variables are all categorical, because there are too many different fitted values. Eg, if they were all binary, there would be a max of 32 fitted values possible. Even w/ >2 levels in a variable (eg, presumaly 4 quarters in a year), there should be a relatively small number of possible values.